# config file in php

Tags: php, class, function, code-reuse

i want to create a user defined config file,which contains some variables with constant values, now i want to access those values in many pages of my application.how can use those variables using functions..what is the best way to do this without using classes.

Comment: You should try to accept more answer 'cause 22% is low and won't motivate ppl to answer you...

Comment: Why not use classes? Asking people to keep two lines as they are (one at the top, one at the bottom) to wrap all their configuration in a class definition should not be harder than asking them to use PHP in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

You can define this file somewhere and include it or require it.

```
require_once("path/to/file/config.php");
```

Any variables within this file are accessible in the script that [requires](https://www.php.net/require)/[includes](https://www.php.net/include) it.

Or you can use define as:

```
define("TEST", "10");    //TEST holds constant 10
```

Now using TEST in all capitals will have the value it was defined as.

Also, if you want them accessible in functions you have three options, pass them as arguments to the function when called or declare as global within function.

```
//example 1
require_once("path/to/file/config.php"); 
function testFunction($var){
   echo $var." inside my function";   //echos contents of $var 
}

//now lets say a variable $test = 10; was defined in config.php
echo $test;    //displays "10" as it was defined in the config file.  all is good
testFunction($test);  //displays "10 inside my function" because $test was passed to function


//example 2
require_once("path/to/file/config.php"); 
function testFunction2(){
   global $test; 
   echo $test; //displays "10" as defined in config.php 
}

//example 3
define("TEST", "10");
echo TEST; // outputs "10"
//could have these constants defined in your config file as described and used above also!
```

Answer (score 1):

Well doing it without classes you could use `define()` to create user based constants to use throughout your application.

**EDIT**
The naming convention for constants are all uppercase chars.

example:

```
define(DATE, date());
```

you can call it in your script by calling :

```
$date = DATE;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Alternatively you can save the details in the `$GLOBALS` array. Remember that this is not completely secure, so use `md5()` to store passwords or sensitive data.

Comment: md5 is not for storing passwords.

Comment: lol i know that ;) My answer may have been a little ambiguous, sorry bout that. I meant md5() any sensitive data in the $GLOBALS array.

Comment: Globals is neither less nor more secure than using `define`. Also, `md5()` effectively destroys the data that it works on, making it useless except for checking that data stored elsewhere is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using constants then `define()` makes sense but you could maybe use [ini files](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) as an alternative instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a couple of ways you can do this

- [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)
- [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)
- [Using XML as a config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087009/php-moving-config-mapping-file-to-xml-but-how-to-i-create-a-dynamic-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

if i have a simple config file like config.ini (it can be htttp://example.com/config.ini, or /etc/myapp/config.ini )

```
user=cacom
version = 2021608
status= true
```

this is my function:

```
function readFileConfig($UrlOrFilePath){

    $lines = file($UrlOrFilePath);
    $config = array();
    
    foreach ($lines as $l) {
        preg_match("/^(?P<key>.*)=(\s+)?(?P<value>.*)/", $l, $matches);
        if (isset($matches['key'])) {
            $config[trim($matches['key'])] = trim($matches['value']);
        }
    }

    return $config;
}
```